# How to remove focus on dropdown button when you already moved mouse away from it?

Tags: html, css, bulma

When i click dropdown button and click it again for closing focus still remains. even when i move mouse away. How can focus removed for that case?

Comment: Without code it's hard to comprehend. Btw you can add an eventListener 'onmouseleave' for the dropdown so that when cursor leaves the dropdown it'll get closed

Comment: @BilalMohammad what kind of code it's just :focus class that remains active when you click it for closing?

Comment: you need to toggle the :focus class on clicking the dropdown, maybe you are jjust adding it and not removing the class on second click

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to remove the focus on the second click with the help of `element.blur()` - here are the related [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur). You can add the class to the button on the first click and if the button has class (it will have on the second click) - just use blur.

But keep in mind, that some users want to interact with your site with the help of a keyboard, and removing focus will be annoying for them. Do you need focus to be visible on the button before opening the dropdown? Another possible solution is to remove `:focus` style from the element completely (`outline: none`), but it's not recommended.